# Failed to decode downloaded font of awesome font

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

My website use the fontawesome https://fontawesome.com/ as the icons. Today when I access the website, the fontawesome icon load failed, then I opened the devtools, shows warning(this website works fine for years, suddenly failed today):

```
OTS parsing error: Size of decompressed WOFF 2.0 is less than compressed size
editor:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/webfonts/fa-regular-400.ttf
editor:1 OTS parsing error:  OS/: misaligned table
editor:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2
editor:1 OTS parsing error: Failed to convert WOFF 2.0 font to SFNT
editor:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf
editor:1 OTS parsing error:  OS/: misaligned table
```

this is how I import the css in `index.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.css">
```

why did this issue suddenly happen? what should I do to fixed it? This it the UI with icon loading issue:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue might be caused by bootcdn.net server configuration. Most mainland China's CDN sites likely have the same issue. It's recommended that using another link instead: https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.2/css/all.css